# Value of Attached Property in ItemsControl, during custom panel implementation

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I implement custom panel `Shelf`, which arrange child based on Attached Property `Shelf.Exact`:

```
class Shelf : Panel
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExactProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Exact", typeof(int), typeof(Shelf),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(100, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnExactChanged)));
    private static void OnExactChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(d); // This Callback is added only for debug purposes
    }
    public static int GetExact(UIElement element)
    {
        return (int)element.GetValue(ExactProperty);
    }
    public static void SetExact(UIElement element, int value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ExactProperty, value);
    }
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Size panelSize = new Size(availableSize.Width, 0);
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            child.Measure(availableSize);
            panelSize.Height += child.DesiredSize.Height;
        }
        return panelSize;
    }
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            int exact = Shelf.GetExact(child); // Here I always get 100 which is default value for ExactProperty
            child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, exact * 1), child.DesiredSize));
        }
        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Packs}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <local:Shelf />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock local:Shelf.Exact="{Binding Path=Number}" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Like I mention in code comment above I always get default value of `Shelf.DependencyProperty`. I can't get why is that?

---

The first idea was that the binding is mess up. So I add `PropertyChangedCallback` and check if changed value get triggered → callback is called and `d.NewValue` is okey but still get default value in `ArrangeOverride()`. Next I get rid of binding at all, so I hardcode `local:Shelf.Exact="123"` → still I get default value.

What's more it works perfect when I use `Shelf` directly:

```
<local:Shelf Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBlock local:Shelf.Exact="223">Test</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock local:Shelf.Exact="332">Test</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock local:Shelf.Exact="443">Test</TextBlock>
</local:Shelf>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextBlock in the DataTemplate is not the element that is measured and arranged by the ItemsPanel.

You'll have to set the attached property on the items container (i.e. a ContentPresenter) in an ItemContainerStyle:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Packs}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <local:Shelf/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="local:Shelf.Exact" Value="{Binding Number}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Worth mentioning link: http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/03/25/itemscontrol-i-is-for-item-container/ which explain the problem.